# Flutter use network images protected with Basic Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, nginx

We have a main site that holds all the user's uploads which are usually just profile pictures.

The folder with all the uploads is protected with *nginx* and the *basic auth*. So you need to enter a username and password to access it.

#### Question

How can this be done using Flutter cached_network_image? Or something similar. We don't want to physically store the images on the device.

Comment: `Image.network` should work just fine

Comment: Thank you will try now

Comment: The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404

Comment: did you use correct  HTTP headers?

Comment: Yes sir! We even tried integrating this with the API that uses JWT tokens and Bearer as Authorisation too.
It works with postman but nothing with flutter works. Its as if the headers are being ignored:


           headers: {
            "Authorization":
                 "Bearer redacted",
           },

Comment: ignored? by a server? or not passed by a client? tried to use devtools to see what is really sent?

Comment: Hey mate, your gonna laugh, it worked, the problem is the rule we set was for POST and not GET, changing the rest route to GET worked! So your resolution is 100% thank you for all your time and help mate, we just have to use the CachedNetworkImage instead.

Comment: good, i'm glad that worked

Comment: @user15076841 Please stop defacing your question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `httpHeaders` property on `CachedNetworkImage` widget to pass custom auth headers.

```dart
CachedNetworkImage(
  imageUrl: ...,
  imageBuilder: ...,
  placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
  httpHeaders: {
    "Authorization": "Basic $token",
  }
),
```

Comment: Thank you I am going to try now.

Comment: This does not work, I get returned with a server status of 404. I do the same thing in postman and it works.

Comment: Okay so this works, it was my fault with the request method on the server side... Thank you!